# ¿Cómo hago para que un collapse de Bootstrap abra hacia arriba?

Tags: html, bootstrap

¿Cómo puedo hacer para cambiar el comportamiento por default del collapse que abre hacia abajo? Lo que necesito es que abra hacia arriba, tipo dropUp.

Dejo el código:

```
<div class="row justify-content-center">
<div class="col-12 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
    <a class="btn btn-blue-card gtm_planer_ver_todo" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseTriplePack" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTriplePack" data-mercado="personas" data-segmento="hogar">
        <h4 class="txt-btn m-0">Ver todos los planes</h4>
    </a>
</div>

<div class="col-12">
    <div class="collapse" id="collapseTriplePack">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-12 mt-3">
                <div class="d-block d-md-flex d-lg-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
                    <h2 class="txt-planes-dep m-0">Todos los planes deportes incluyen <strong>Fox Sport Premium</strong></h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Deberias agregar tu codigo

Comment: @alanfcm listo código de referencia agregado

Comment: Ya revisaste los dropUps? https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/dropdowns/#dropup

Comment: Saludos. ¿Ya probaste colocando primero lo que corresponde a la clase `collapse`arriba de los botones? (Claro todo el bloque conforme tu diseño).

Comment: @RobertoLeOr eso funcionó. Gracias!